# Reading quicken data files

Tags: c#, java, python, file-format, quicken

Looking for an open source library, for C++, Java, C# or Python, for reading the data from Quicken **.qdf** files.

@Swati:  Quicken **.qif** format is for transfer only and is not kept up to date by the application  like the .qdf file is.

Comment: It really is too bad Intuit doesn't have a Google-style Data Liberation policy (http://www.dataliberation.org/).  My biggest fear with Quicken is that it disappears and I'm locked into it forever.  But they keep .qdf very proprietary (and encrypted)...

Comment: https://github.com/isaacharrisholt/quiffen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QDF is proprietary and not really meant for reading other than my Quicken, probably for a reason as it is messy.

I would recommend finding a way to export the qdf into an OFX (Open Financial Exchange) or qif file.  I have done some financial and quickbooks automation and I did something similar.  The problem is if you don't export to an exchange format, each version differs and strange things happen for many conditions that since they aren't documented (QDF) it becomes a bad situation for the programmer.

OFX is what allows online banking, brokerages and apps like mint.com securely get financial data.  It is a standard and consistent.  Finding a way to this is much better if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/10491.aspx

And i know one other blog where the author was developing a parser for qfx/qif... lemme look it up... googling hasnt helped yet :(

Update: Found one more:

http://blogs.msdn.com/lucabol/archive/2007/08/31/parsing-qif-quicken-files-in-c.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://qif.codeplex.com/

You may want to check the license before use. Thanks

Comment: That link is down.